# How to insert a table in a beamer block?

Tags: beamer

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t] \frametitle{title}
    \begin{block}
        \begin{tabular}{ccc}
         cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
         cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\  
         cell7 & cell8 & cell9    
        \end{tabular}
    \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This ends up with a fatal error.

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\end #1->\csname end#1
                      \endcsname \@checkend {#1}\expandafter \endgroup \if@e...
l.12 \end{frame}

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

How to insert a tabular in a beamer block? If tabulars are not able to insert in a block, is there any alternative method that can align text. I have tried several of them such as tabularx and align, but with no success.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

Beamer `block`s need a title, even if it is empty using `{}`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t] \frametitle{title}
    \begin{block}{}
        \begin{tabular}{ccc}
         cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
         cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\  
         cell7 & cell8 & cell9    
        \end{tabular}
    \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow. It works like a charm. But why? I saw a post that says the above fatal error means the code causes an infinite loop, but that post is not talking about beamer.

Comment: @KevinDong The problem is that beamer blocks need the title as mandatory argument.

Comment: Thanks for saving my time. I did not notice I forgot a title.

Comment: @KevinDong You're welcome!